# Grails. Testing command objects with spring beans inside

Tags: spring, unit-testing, grails, spock, command-objects

I have a command object with constraints using spring beans in custom validator:

```
class UserPasswordCommand {
    String currentPassword
    //other fields....
    static constraints = {
        currentPassword validator: { currPass, upc ->
            Holders.applicationContext.passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(
                    Holders.applicationContext.springSecurityService.currentUser.password, currPass, null)
        }
    }
}
```

But when invoking *new UserPasswordCommand(...)* in unit test I get the following:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'currentUser' on
>   null object

So it appears that springSecurityService = null (as expected). I tried different actions to mock or "metaClass" it but unsuccessful.

Please advise if there is a better way to use beans from applicationContext in command objects or some approaches of mocking beans in Holders.applicationContext.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Placed the following to `setup()` section:

```
def setup() {
    def appContext = Mock(ApplicationContext)
    def springSecurityService = Mock(SpringSecurityService)
    appContext.springSecurityService >> springSecurityService
    Holders.metaClass.static.applicationContext = { appContext }
}
```

But no effect. springSecurityService is **null** in *applicationContext* retrieved from *Holders*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just FYI using Holders in a command object is a really bad idea. It will perform poorly. The better way to do it is to make the beans constructor arguments and construct the class yourself.

Comment: @JamesKleeh, thanks for info. I changed retrieving from Holders to a normal DI and made the fields static. Is this solution good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by getting rid of `Holders` in the original command object:

```
class UserPasswordCommand {
    static passwordEncoder
    static springSecurityService
    String currentPassword
    //...
    static constraints = {
        currentPassword validator: { currPass, upc ->
    passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(springSecurityService.currentUser.password, currPass, null)
        }
    //...
    }
}
```

Added the mocks/stubs to test test:

```
def springSecurityService = Mock(SpringSecurityService)
def passwordEncoder = Mock(PasswordEncoder)

def setup() {
    passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(_, _, _) >> Boolean.TRUE
    springSecurityService.currentUser >> Mock(User)
}
```

and:

```
given:
Map props = [
    currentPassword: CURRENT_PASSWORD,
    passwordEncoder: passwordEncoder,
    springSecurityService: springSecurityService,
]

expect:
new UserPasswordCommand(props).validate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override Holder.applicationContext like this:

```
  def setup() {
    ApplicationContext appContext = Mock()
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = Mock()
    passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(_, _, _) >> true

    appContext.passwordEncoder >> passwordEncoder //you can do the same for springSecurityService

    //override Holder.getAplicationContext() method to return mocked context
    Holders.metaClass.static.applicationContext = { appContext }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `Holders` instead of `Holder`? And probably `metaClass` instead of `metaclass`?

Comment: Yep, sorry I had no access to the notebook, I have just corrected my answer

Comment: No effect. I've updated the question with the new `setup()` section.